# Connecting Metabase with Docker SQL or Docker MongoDB container

Tags: mysql, mongodb, docker, metabase

I am trying to connect my Metabase docker container to my containers database containers.
`docker ps`
[image]

Metabase container created such as the docs:
`docker run -d -p 3000:3000 --name metabase metabase/metabase`

This are my networks: 
[image]

mongodb container and mysql container are also connected to the control-panel-back, but I don't think that matters. Either way: when I tried to connect the databases it gives me the following error:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used the IP of the connection.

`docker network ls`

`docker inspect network_name`

Use the IPAM.Config.Gateway for the Host.